# SQL Server Replication - Stored Procedure Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, replication, database-replication

I've been trying to configure a simple publication to replicate stored procedure execution as per [this post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqltact/2013/09/04/replicated-stored-procedure-execution/) but no matter what I try every time I execute the SP on the Publisher db the updates get pushed row by row to the subscriber rather than calling the expected SP (ie I see a number of exec [sp_MSins_dboTestArticle] commands when profiling the subscriber database rather than a single call to the addheaprows SP).

I've followed all the instructions on multiple websites including MSDN (setting the SP article properties, calling it in a Serializable transaction) and simply can't get this to work. The publication is set up as Transactional on SQL Server 2014 with a single Pull Subscriber (I've also tried push).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, could there be something obvious I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Comment: That linked-to article has crappy instructions. What is the value of the `@type` parameter for the call to `sp_addarticle`? If you're adding the article through the GUI, choose the "script" option rather than let the GUI complete it to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's because I had cdc enabled which isn't compatible with stored proc replication - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2013/04/28/cannot-replicate-stored-procedure-execution-when-cdc-is-enabled/